# Packages installed in Conda env does not show up in Pycharm

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm, conda

I'm struggling to understand why Pycharm is not recognizing OpenCV package installed via Conda.

[Conda list command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50EkJ.png)

[Pycharm package list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6G6Us.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that a few times before as well but not as much lately. The **first** thing I would try is to upgrade to the latest version of PyCharm.

You may just want to peruse their forum if that doesn't help, but it sounds more like a bug to me.

[PyCharm Support Forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&topic=200379535&query=package%20list)